# Axiomatic probability intersection formula

Tags: probability

I'm new to probability and I'm currently studying its axiomatic definition. I'm having a real hard time trying to understand the following exercise:

"
Tomorrow there is an exam. Esther has studied really hard, and she only has  $\frac 1 5$ probability of not passing the exam.

David has studied less, and he has $\frac 1 3$  probability of not passing the exam. We know that the probability of both not passing the exam is $\frac 1 8$.

What is the probability that at least one of them does not pass the exam?
"

From the statement, we know that $P(A\cap B)=\dfrac{1}{8}$

My question is: How is that value achieved? How is it that the intersection of $\dfrac{1}{5}$ and $\dfrac{1}{3}$ equals $\dfrac{1}{8}$?

Thanks in advanced for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: How is that value achieved? How is it that the intersection of $\tfrac{1}{5}$ and $\tfrac{1}{3}$ equals $\tfrac{1}{8}$?

Well,  $\frac 18<\min\{\frac 15,\frac 13\}$ so this is possible.    Knowing $\mathsf P(A)$ and $\mathsf P(B)$ does not *alone* tell you what $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ is; just that $0\leq\mathsf P(A\cap B)\leq\min\{\mathsf P(A),\mathsf P(B)\}$.   The intersection of two events *may* be anything from empty, to being the entirety of the smallest event.

Okay, *when* the events are independent, *then* the probability of their intersection is the product of their probabilities.   However, *because* this probability is not that, *therefore* David' and Esther's performances on the exam are not independent.

Perhaps they shared faulty study materiel.   It doesn't really matter.

You want to find $\mathsf P(A\cup B)$ knowing $\mathsf P(A), \mathsf P(B),$ and $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$.   You *can* do that.